# Does Thomae's function have an antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x)=1/q$ if $x=p/q\in \mathbb{Q}$, $p,q$ coprime natural numbers (restrict to $[1,2]$ to make things easier). By boundedness and as it has at most countably many discontinuous points we know that $f$ is integrable on $[1,2]$. Does it have antiderivative on such a compact?

Comment: The function $F(x) = 0$ is an antiderivative *almost everywhere*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; for the sake of contradiction suppose it did. Then, there is a function $F$ such that $F' = f$ on the compact interval $[1,2]$. Note that derivatives have the intermediate-value-property, but we have $F'(1) = f(1)= 1$ and $F'\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right) = f\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)= \dfrac{1}{2}$. This means that the entire interval $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ must lie in the image of $F' = f$. However, the image of $f$ is a subset of the rational numbers. Thus, we have a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice argument thank you

Comment: You wrote the simpler argument and hence I had to write a less simple one. +1

Comment: Somehow I missed a discrepancy here and I guess you missed it in the same manner as I and other upvoters missed while reading. We have $f(2)=1$. The right choice would be $f(3/2)=1/2$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh thank you that's such an obvious mistake, but even after your comment it took me 5 minutes to figure out why it was wrong lol... I had literally convinced myself that $2=1/2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another argument. Suppose there is an anti-derivative $F$. By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have $$F(x) =F(1)+\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ for all $x\in[1,2]$. Since $F'=f$ it follows from above equation that we have $g'=f$ where $g$ is defined by $$g(x) =\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ But notice that integral of Thomae function is $0$ over any interval and hence $g$ and $g'$ are both identically $0$. And this gives our contradiction as $f=g'$ is not identically zero (it is non-zero on rationals).